# I am trying to automatically apply a filter to a column - and sort the sheet in descending order by that column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to have the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NnGin38iNuyBfrEYMOSVhoylO_cNlw5dFt9FqlqVSHY/edit?usp=sharing) automatically sort by `Column B`, in descending order. However the raw data as the *"-" text* so I'm using the formula in `Column C` `"=abs(B2)"` and then trying to filter by `Column C` instead.

I would like the sheet to automatically apply the filter and then sort when edits are made. I've been playing with the Apps Script but cannot get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
    function myFunction() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      ss.getRange ("C2").setFormula("=abs(B2)");
    
      var lr = ss.getLastRow();
      var fillDownRange = ss.getRange (2,3, lr-1);
      ss.getRange("C2").copyTo(fillDownRange);      
    }
    
    function autosort(){    
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Trustlines")
      const range = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,3)
    
      range.sort({column: 3, ascending: false})    
    }
    
    
    function onEdit(e){    
      const row = e.range.getRow()
      const column = e.range.getColumn()
    
      if(!(column === 3 && row>= 2)) return
    
      autosort()    
    }
```

Comment: The sheet application already allows you to sort by column. Is there a reason to not use that?

Comment: I'm just trying to automate the process - with the hopes of having the data pull in directly from a website using the importHTML function (still working on that part too). Instead of having to manually adjust the filter and sort each time, it would be nice if it's already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not want to get your data from `IMPORTHTML`. The main reason for that is that the `onEdit` trigger is not triggered unless the user changes some data (witch is probably not what you want to use).

What I would propose instead is to make all the calculations using Apps Script and only adding to the spreadsheet the result. This will be done following this steps:

1. Get the page source. This can be done using `UrlFetchApp`.
2. Interpret the source and extract the data. `XmlService` should allow you to do so.
3. Filter and sort the data. Use the native `sort` and `filter` JavaScript Array methods.
4. Add the result as values on the sheet.

### References

- [Simple Triggers (Google Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [URL Fetch Service (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch)
- [XML Service (Google Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)
- [Array.prototype.sort() (MDN JavaScript reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [Array.prototype.filter() (MDN JavaScript reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank your for this feedback and guidance! I am very new at using Apps Scripts and it's always great to have direction from those more experienced! I would have been banging my head against the wall for hours I'm sure (not including the hours already put into it). Much appreciated!

Comment: @pdaniels1226 I'm glad it helped. It's nice to see people trying to learn how to do it and doing it by themselves :)  Also, if this answers your question, the way to mark it as answered to other people is by [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/899642).